# How to set an <h1> value from an API response?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have been trying to set a page title based on an API response. My HTML is:

```
<h1 id='league_name'></h1>
```

My Javascript is:

```
<script>
      fetch('https://api.example.com')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        var name = JSON.stringify(json)
        document.getElementById('league_name').innerHTML = name;
      });
      </script>
```

But it stays blank. The API response is just a single string

Comment: Pleaae log your response json, i thing your request have a error handle ‘catch’ callBackfunction

Comment: Why two `then`s?

Comment: @GetSet That's normal. You need one to parse the JSON, the next to process the resulting object.

Comment: Why parse it and then stringify it again ?

Comment: Is the API response string in quotes? If not, it's not valid JSON and you should use `response.text()` instead of `response.json()`. Either way, the `JSON.stringify` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your URL is not working. it is main reason.
I have used mockAPI: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/
now it works as expected

Also `JSON.stringify` is not necessary, because data already parsed by `.json()`

```html
<h1 id='league_name'></h1>
<script>
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2')
      .then(response => {
      return response.json();
      })
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user)
        document.getElementById('league_name').innerHTML = user.name;
      }).catch(e => console.log(e))
</script>
```